# JavaFX adding rows of data from one tabel to another table

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to add rows which I selected in one table to another table. I'm not sure how to dynamically append rows. The code I did so far just changes the first row.

```
int hr = 1;
if ( hr == 1){
    ObservableList<TableColumn<ObservableList<StringProperty>, ?>> header = tableId.getColumns();
    auswTable.getColumns().addAll(header);
    hr = 2;
}
    ObservableList<ObservableList<StringProperty>> content = 
            tableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    auswTable.setItems(content);
```

Comment: help me understanding your question , when ever user selected a row in Table1 ,it will be automatically added Table2 ? or when user selected some rows in Table1 after that if he click on addToTable2 button then data should be added to Table 2 ?

Comment: the second one. the user should be able to select a row in table1 (tableId in the code). if the user clicks on addToTable2 the row should be appear in Table2 (auswTable). the if statement transmits the columns and titles.

Comment: right now it just sends one row to table2 and exchanges its content every time the user clicks the button. I like to add more rows in table2 from table1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> right now it just sends one row to table2 and exchanges its content
>   every time the user clicks the button. I like to add more rows in
>   table2 from table1.

This was happening because In your code for table2, you set selectedItems observable list as setItems ,so when ever user selected a row/rows in table 1 ,it will automatically added table2. To fix this issue define a new ObserbaleList for table2 and add values from selecteditems to it.

Sample Code :

```
private  ObservableList<ObservableList<StringProperty>> table2Observable =  
                                            FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private boolean init = true;

  if(init) {

      ObservableList<TableColumn<ObservableList<StringProperty>, ?>> header =  
                          tableId.getColumns();
     auswTable.getColumns().addAll(header);
     auswTable.setItems(table2Observable);
     init = false;
    }

     table2Observable.addAll(tableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```